# most frequent words in python , I get error (TypeError: unhashable type: 'list') while running

Tags: python, nlp

I wrote code below but I get error (TypeError: unhashable type: 'list') while running , can you help me ? i want most frequent words in my token.

```
! pip install wget
import wget
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dirkhovy/NLPclass/master/data/moby_dick.txt'
wget.download(url, 'moby_dick.txt')
documents = [line.strip() for line in open('moby_dick.txt', encoding='utf8').readlines()]

import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')

tokens = [[token.text for token in nlp(sentence)] for sentence in documents[:200]]



from collections import Counter
# your code here

# Pass the split_it list to instance of Counter class. 

Counter = Counter(tokens) 

# most_common() produces k frequently encountered 
# input values and their respective counts. 
most_occur = Counter.most_common(10) 

print(most_occur)
```

the error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      4 # Pass the split_it list to instance of Counter class.
      5 
----> 6 Counter = Counter(tokens)
      7 
      8 # most_common() produces k frequently encountered

1 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/collections/**init**.py in update(*args, **kwds)
    620                     super(Counter, self).update(iterable) # fast path when counter is empty
    621             else:
--> 622                 _count_elements(self, iterable)
    623         if kwds:
    624             self.update(kwds)

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Did this helped @elham?

Comment: I updated the error

Comment: what error do you get when you run my solution? @elham

Comment: your sol didnt work , I run another solution, because we should change the format of tokens to be a simple list not list of list.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict(Counter(map(tuple, token))).most_common())
```

If above code did not help try to downgrade your spacy.

Try to install below packages:

```
pip install msgpack==0.5.6 spacy==2.0.13 https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref-models/releases/download/en_coref_md-3.0.0/en_coref_md-3.0.0.tar.gz
```

or

```
python -m venv neuralcoref
source neuralcoref/bin/activate
CFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++' pip install thinc==6.10.3
pip install msgpack==0.5.6
CFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++' pip install spacy==2.0.12  # <-- not 2.0.13
pip install https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref-models/releases/download/en_coref_lg-3.0.0/en_coref_lg-3.0.0.tar.gz
```

Comment: sorry mahsa jan what is this?

Comment: Try to downgraded your spacy==2.0.12 and I think this issue can be solved.

Comment: @elham also please do  it:  dict(Counter(map(tuple, token))).most_common())

Comment: it tells me this is invalid syntax

Comment: Omit dict and use just: Counter(map(tuple, token))).most_common(), let me know if you could solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
! pip install wget
import wget
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dirkhovy/NLPclass/master/data/moby_dick.txt'
wget.download(url, 'moby_dick.txt')
documents = [line.strip() for line in open('moby_dick.txt', encoding='utf8').readlines()]

import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')

tokens = [token.text for sentence in documents[:200] for token in nlp(sentence)]



from collections import Counter

Counter = Counter(tokens) 

most_occur = Counter.most_common(10) 

print(most_occur)
```

update your syntax of list comprehension